# rails api for existing oracle tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a rails api application that connects to an existing oracle database

I have managed to create api's for the existing oracle tables using ruby-oci, oracle enhanced  adapter and simple scaffolding, but how do I add all the pk, fk and index information to the models for each table?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you have already setup your model and you have already setup the primary key as Mahatmanich said.

```
set.table_name="schema.table"
set.primary_key="legacy_id"
```

I also set aliases for all of my legacy table fields so that they are more readable within my code base.

```
alias :alias_name, :old_field_name
```

Usually with dealing with legacy databases the relationships aren't as straight forward as having a single primary key.  Here are a few examples;

```
 belongs_to :the_other_table,
   :class_name => 'TheOtherClassName',
   :primary_key => 'key_in_other_table',
   :foreign_key => 'my_key'

 has_many :yet_another_tables,
   :class_name => "YetAnotherClassName",
   :primary_key => 'my_key_2', 
   :foreign_key => 'key_in_yet_another_table',
   :conditions => ['something = ?', true]
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi the best place to find this information is here: https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced

Should be pretty straight forward, in your model do this:

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name="Test"
  self.primary_key="id"
end
```